# Android APK expansion and viewView

Tags: android, file, apk, android-videoview, expansion

I'm developing an Android application, that exceeds 50mb, so after made a research, I mande an expansion file.

The problem that I'm having is with my videoview. The Expansion file contains all the required videos, and I can't get the path to those videos.

Before, I was using this code:

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://com.package.acerp/"+ videoName;
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uriPath);
```

This code works fine, but now, I can't read from my expansion file. I'm doing this:

```
CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.package.provider.ZipContentProvider");
Uri uriPath = Uri.parse((CONTENT_URI + "/" + videoName + ".mp4"));
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uriPath);
```

Wich returns my fileNotFound...
I'm also created this class:

```
public class ZipContentProvider extends APEZProvider {
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.package.provider";

    public static Uri buildUri(String pathIntoApk) {
        StringBuilder contentPath = new StringBuilder("content://");

        contentPath.append(AUTHORITY);
        contentPath.append(File.separator);
        contentPath.append(pathIntoApk);

        return Uri.parse(contentPath.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return AUTHORITY;
    }
}
```

And put some info in my manifest file:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.package.ZipContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.package.provider"
        android:exported="true" />
```

What am I missing? Thanks...